# Access Control Width

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two lines of codes here:

`CreateReportControl Title, acLabel, acPageHeader, , FieldName.Name, 0, 0, 600`
`CreateReportControl Title, acTextBox, acDetail, , FieldName.Name, 0, 0, 600`

As you can see, they are largely similar, just that the label is put into the page header section while the textbox is left in the details section.

However, in execution, only the Textbox actually takes on the specified width of 600 but not the label. The label actually determines its width according to the length of the caption within. Any idea why this happens and how can I force them to take on the same length, which is 600 in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `FieldName.Name` for the *ColumnName* option.  However the *Application.CreateReportControl Method* help topic says *"ColumnName Optional Variant The name of the field to which the control will be bound, if it is to be a data-bound control."*

Since a label is not a data-bound control, leave out the ColumnName option.

```vb
'CreateReportControl Title, acLabel, acPageHeader, , FieldName.Name, 0, 0, 600
CreateReportControl Title, acLabel, acPageHeader, , , 0, 0, 600
```

This is just a wild guess, but shouldn't take much effort to rule out.